# Icon next to the build job list not showing up in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a problem with one of my coworkers is not able to see the build icon next to each job. I already tried to make the permissions in `Manage Jenkins -> Configure Settings -> Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy` to be the same as mine but I can see the icon and my coworker can't, so any help would be appreciated.

I'm attaching a picture so everyone knows what I'm talking about. It's the red square box that my co-worker is not able to see.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins we can configure the dashboard, please check the url https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem is related to permissions more than the display of the icon.

Comment: Can you show what permissions have given to the co-worker in matrix authentication. If you provide read only permissions he/she cannot view the build option.

Comment: As I specified in the question, I gave the user same permissions as me and other administrators that are able to see the build button.